# How to run F-Logic programs?

Tags: logic, semantics

I've found many tutorials about the language it self, but nothing about the platform needed in order to run it.

There's a github repository which only runs on mac, not sure if it's flogic itself. I know it's being used for semantic web so I thought that would be easy to find some oficial docs and use instructions.